# how to get images and texts to display on my app on Heroku using rails 5

Tags: html, css, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

here's my app on Heroku
https://forks-app.herokuapp.com/
i've look online but im not sure if I need the image_tag with rails 5.
Could anyone suggest how to get this to display?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need the image tag.

But the bigger issue is that Heroku does not store images on its server (or at least not for long). You need an external storage service for that - e.g. Amazon S3.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3 for a guide on setting up Amazon S3.